# MySQL query cost goes up when remove order by

Tags: mysql, performance

[image: Without Order]
[image: With Order]

I have two tables that I'm running a simple query on. I was having some performance issues with it, and I noticed that if I simplify the query by removing the order by, the explain plan actually becomes worse. I would've figured that explain plan would've become better since I simplified the query, but the exact opposite occurred.

My question is, why would this happen?

```
Query cost with order by: 399,210.33
Query cost without order by: 648,450.33


SELECT count(alpha.id) AS object_value, bravo.company_id AS object_id 
FROM alpha 
INNER JOIN bravo ON alpha.bravo_id = bravo.id 
WHERE alpha.completed_at >= date('2015-08-01') AND alpha.completed_at <= date('2017-08-10')
GROUP BY object_id
ORDER BY object_value desc;
```

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for osx10.11 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

[image: Show Status with Order]

[image: Show Status without Order]

Comment: And you've eliminated the possibility of disk caching causing the difference?

Comment: I flushed and reset the query cache and reran the test. Same result.

Comment: Show us the EXPLAIN for the query with order by and without order by..

Comment: please note if your remove the ORDER BY MySQL is still using ORDER BY object_id because off the GROUP BY

Comment: When you reran the test, did you run the queries in the same order again or reverse them? Or did you run them on their own separate cache clears?

Comment: @Uueerdo I flushed, ran, flushed, ran. Order didn't seem to matter.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I added screenshots of the explain plan.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` only produces estimates. How does this query *actually* run?

Comment: Perform a `FLUSH STATUS;`, run one query, then run `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'handler_read%';` Repeat for the other query. Then post the results of the `handler_read` output.

Comment: @tadman I'm running this query in MySQL workbench for testing purposes.

Comment: @bishop I did as you asked. Strangely the output is the same. 
I ran flush, query1, show session. Then flush, query2, show session.

Comment: What I mean is check real-world performance with the query, not just `EXPLAIN` which produces wild guesstimates. Postgres, to compare, has a far better query analyzer and one that can tell you the execution times of an actual query. It has both `EXPLAIN`, which makes a guess, and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` which [actually runs the query and measures the results](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/using-explain.html). I'm not sure if MySQL has an equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EXPLAIN` and the Optimizer statistics are *approximate*.

Do you have `INDEX(completed_at, bravo_id)`?  It should help performance.

Rewrite the query thus:

```
SELECT  count(*) AS object_value,  -- no need to test alpha.id for not-NULL
        bravo.company_id AS object_id
    FROM  alpha
    INNER JOIN  bravo  ON alpha.bravo_id = bravo.id
    WHERE  alpha.completed_at >= '2015-08-01'
      AND  alpha.completed_at  < '2015-08-01' + INTERVAL 9 DAY  -- avoids extra second, leap calc, etc
    GROUP BY  object_id
    ORDER BY  object_value desc;
```

The 'Handler' values are exact; the `EXPLAIN` values are guesstimates.

The `ORDER BY` is probably not a big deal.  How many rows in the result set?  If not millions, the sort will probably be done in RAM.

I would expect the `ORDER BY` to require a second filesort.  Where there any `Handler...write` values?

What produced the graphical output?  Does it agree with `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`?